# I have accidentally delete allow on ssh from ufw

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, google-compute-engine

I have configured a flask app on Googles compute engine/ vm instances and when I removed 'Nginx HTTP' rules from **ufw, I accidentaly removed 'OpenSSH'** rule also.
When I try to connect to ssh `ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection timed out connection cannot be established.`

There is any way of regaining access to this vm?

Comment: I don't know the Google specifics but with other providers you would have a virtual console that you can connect to from you user account.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reboot and hope for the file /etc/iptables/rules.v4 to be present and have your SSH rule inside.

Otherwise, revert to a previous snapshot of your VM, and if you don't have one, well...sorry

Comment: I didn't find a way to connect to my VM so I had to build it again.